# Controlling the linewidth aesthetic of a geom_sf using a column that contains weight values

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am trying to use a numeric column called `weight` as the linewidth aesthetic of my `geom_sf`. The values in the column are 1 and 2.
When I do that, the lines with the weight of 2 are too big and the legend seems like `ggplot` is treating my scale as continuous.

I am using:

```
  ggeom_sf(data = roads, mapping = aes(geometry = geometry , color=class, linewidth = weight)) +
  scale_size_identity() +
```

The lines with weight of 1 are decently sized but the lines with the weight of 2 are too big.

What's going on here?

Comment: Try `scale_ linewidth_identity()`.

Comment: @stefan this worked like charm. Thank you. ChatGPT had already suggested this solution to me but since I was not using the latest version of `ggplot2`, the function was not available. I therefore dismissed that solution as just another mishap of the bot. Now that I have upgraded my `ggplot2` installation, the function is there and it works well for my needs.